# fletcher checksum giving different values

Tags: c, checksum

I am trying to use a 16-bit Fletcher checksum here. Basically, my program simulates traffic over the physical layer by "sending" and "receiving" packets between two virtual entities. I am printing out the packets at both sides and they do match, but I am getting a different checksum calculated at the receiving end.

Packet structure:

```
#define  MESSAGE_LENGTH  20
struct   pkt {
    int  seqnum;
    int  acknum;
    int  checksum;
    char payload[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
};
```

This is the code I'm using to compute the checksum of each packet:

```
/*
 * Computes the fletcher checksum of the input packet
 */
uint16_t calcChecksum(struct pkt *packet) {
    /* the data for the checksum needs to be continuous, so here I am making
       a temporary block of memory to hold everything except the packet checksum */
    size_t sizeint = sizeof(int);
    size_t size = sizeof(struct pkt) - sizeint;
    uint8_t *temp = malloc(size);
    memcpy(temp, packet, sizeint * 2);   // copy the seqnum and acknum
    memcpy(temp + (2*sizeint), &packet->payload, MESSAGE_LENGTH);  // copy data

    // calculate checksum
    uint16_t checksum = fletcher16((uint8_t const *) &temp, size);
    free(temp);
    return checksum;
}

/*
 * This is a checksum algorithm that I shamelessly copied off a wikipedia page.
 */
uint16_t fletcher16( uint8_t const *data, size_t bytes ) {
    uint16_t sum1 = 0xff, sum2 = 0xff;
    size_t tlen;

    while (bytes) {
            tlen = bytes >= 20 ? 20 : bytes;
            bytes -= tlen;
            do {
                    sum2 += sum1 += *data++;
            } while (--tlen);
            sum1 = (sum1 & 0xff) + (sum1 >> 8);
            sum2 = (sum2 & 0xff) + (sum2 >> 8);
    }
    /* Second reduction step to reduce sums to 8 bits */
    sum1 = (sum1 & 0xff) + (sum1 >> 8);
    sum2 = (sum2 & 0xff) + (sum2 >> 8);
    return sum2 << 8 | sum1;
}
```

I don't know much about checksums and I copied that algorithm off a page I found, so if anyone can understand why the checksums for two otherwise identical packets are different I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are not passing the address of `temp` data to the checksum function but rather the address to where the variable `temp` is stored on stack.

You should change

```
uint16_t checksum = fletcher16((uint8_t const *) &temp, size);
```

to

```
uint16_t checksum = fletcher16((uint8_t const *) temp, size);
                                                ^ no & operator
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly now. Originally temp was not a pointer but when I changed that I forgot to change the fletcher call.